# Make parameters that get from function to be able for accessing from others sub

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, c#-to-vb.net

I want to access parameters that sent to function in my class without declare variable above my class to be represent it i meant like this

```
 Public Sub InitializeForm(ByVal Title As String, DocCode As String, BillNo As String)

    Me.Text = Title
    Me.txtDocCode.Text = DocCode
    Me.txtBillNo.Text = BillNo

End Sub
```

and i want to access variable named "DoccCode" from this sub in same class

```
Private Sub SaveData
       //i want to access DocCode from here without declare another variable to be define
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to declare either a `global variable` or a `Property` which will hold the value.
However, since you are setting the value to a textbox, assuming that the value won't change, you can read the value directly from the textbox, as below;

```
Private Sub SaveData

       dim x as string = txtDocCode.Text
End sub
```

Otherwise, if the value might be subject to change, and you wish to preserve the initial value, you can proceed as below;

```
Public Class MyClass

 ' Global variable to hold the value
 Private Doc as string

 Public Sub InitializeForm(ByVal Title As String, DocCode As String, BillNo As String)

    Doc = DocCode
    Me.Text = Title
    Me.txtDocCode.Text = DocCode
    Me.txtBillNo.Text = BillNo

 End Sub

 Private Sub SaveData

   ' Doc variable will still be available 
 End sub

End Class
```

Comment: The first of your acvise is something that i expected  Thank you very much I for get to thought that that value is already stored in textbox     Thank you verymuch